# how google crawls dynamic pages?

Tags: php, seo, search-engine, googlebot

I am about to create an Online Shopping site for my one of the client. I have to make this site SEO Friendly and therefore I must have to understand few things before I proceed to make a custom CMS Based website.

As I said I am going to make a Custom CMS Based website so that my client will be able to add new content through CMS but I don't understand few things.

**For Example:** I have an `index.php` page which has many links to different products and all of these links are created through Database using PHP. Site Link like

http://www.def.com/shoes/Men-Shoes

**My Questions:**

1) I want to know that when the `GoogleBot` crawls my site, will it also open my dynamically created links and index them? Will `GoogleBot` also index the content of my dynamic links?

2) Do I have to create seperate pages for all of the products on site and store them on my server? Or just a single page which serves dynamically according to user query for every product?

I read this

*"It functions much like your web browser, by sending a request to a web server for a web page, downloading the entire page, then handing it off to Google’s indexer."*

is it right?

my above query was actually looking like this and I used .htaccess file to make it pretty

http://www.def.com/shoes.php?type=Men-Shoes

so is it right and google will crawl it to index?

Comment: This is off-topic here. Your example is a link in an html page, googlebot will see it as such, it has no way to know it was generated by PHP.  There is a universe of articles about google SEO (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: Your quote is correct.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I read tens of these pages on SEO but could not find the answer to my second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is a complex science in itself and Google is always changing the goal posts and modifying their algorithm.

While you don't need to create separate pages for each product, creating friendly URL's using the .htaccess file can make them look better and easier to navigate.  Also creating a site map and submitting this to Google Via their webmaster tools will help them to know which pages to index.

GoogleBot will follow the links in your site, including dynamically created one, but it is important not to try and game the system using Blackhat methods if long term success is your aim.

Also, use social media (Twitter, Facebook, Google+) to help promote your brand and make sure you follow Google's guidelines with regards to SEO and inpage optimisation.

There is a huge amount of information on the internet on this subject, but be careful what advice you follow.

Comment: So I don't have to create seperate pages for different products but a single dynamic page which serves the content and using .htaccess and sitemap. right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done in the past.  Google will only see the page and it's content and not the code used to generate the page.  For example.  The page might be shopdomain.com/product?name=toy&id=1002 could be changed to shopdomain.com/product/toy/1002.

Comment: Sir can you answer my query edit of last 3 lines.

Comment: Yes that looks good, but I recommend reading this article by Google regarding https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?rd=1

Answer (score 0):

Google and other search engines index the dynamic links too. So a way to avoid duplicate content is to use the "Crawl"->"URL Parameters" tool in Google Webmasters. You can read more about how that works here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?rd=1. Set "Crawl" field to "No URLs". By this way you could hide from search dynamic links but you have to have a list of all of your dynamic links of your website/CMS in order not to hide important content accidentally. The "URL Parameters" feature is available in Bing Webmaster tools also http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2195777/bing-webmaster-tools-an-overview#.